# iterating over an array of objects and adding to an earlier element...is any more efficient than iterating over a small portion?

Tags: ruby

I have a list of say 1000 objects. I want to add a field in each object to represent the standard deviation on the last 20 objects. By the end of the list I'll have 980 rolling standard deviations and 20 nils.

If I iterate over the list and find the stdev, but I push it to an element 20 objects before, what type of problem is that? Is that a 2n problem?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
(0...thelist.length-20).each do |n|
       ...do some calculations on n 
       if n == 20:
           ...use the calculations to calculate stdev
           thelist[n-20].push(stdeviation)
       end
end
```

Basically I'm wondering how the `[n-20]` affects the theoretical speed of the function.

I could also do something like the below to calculate standard deviation, but I feel like the top one would be faster because I'm calculating more on each individual element vs the below which does an iteration on 20 elements. Is there any difference in speed?

```
 (0...thelist.length-20).each do |n|
       (n..n+20).each do |m|
            ...calculate stdev
       end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stddev` is `sqrt(variance)`. Population variance is the mean of the sum of squares of the population.  You say you want the running stddev over sublists of 20 elements.  So you could calculate this faster by starting by calculating the sum of the squares of the first 20 elements, then iterate through the remaining elements, subtracting the square of the n-20th element and adding the square of the new element and calculating `sqrt(current_sum_of_squares/20.0)` for the stddev.  This will result in about a factor of 20 fewer computations as calculating the stddev independently over N-20 20-element sub-lists.

Pushing the stdev onto the n-20th element is trivial as it doesn't involve any major mutation to the big list, just an append to that one element.

I've gotta run to a meeting now or I'd show some code.  Perhaps later tonight if this isn't clear.

Comment: Regarding the sum of the squares, can you please provide the code? I actually asked this question because I derived what you are referring to but conceptually couldn't figure out whether it was a quicker formula. I'd like to compare your notes to mine. It was a lot more difficult than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about theoretical speed, but I would use [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and look into speed when it becomes a practical problem.

Comment: cool, didn't know they had that. However I do have to say speed is becoming an issue which is why I have a more complicated way of calculating standard deviation. each_cons looks to be essentially the same as the function I provided which had a double loop

Comment: actually without the block that method might be quicker...it doesn't seem to loop

Comment: It does loop, but it loops in C, (or JAVA or C++ depending of your Ruby implementation) ; you just don't have to think about it.